# Android Testing Tools - Youtube

Tags: android, testing, youtube

I would like to implement a testing solution which can run on an actual android device (i.e.  galaxy Tab)

The tool should allow me to open a browser and browse to youtube. Then it should play a video. I want to catch any errors such as video freezing or stopping abruptly.

Any suggestions of any open source tools welcome.

Thanks in Adavnce

Answer (score 1):

Try [robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/), it may be suitable for your scenario.